# Basic of $n$-fold iterations

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Here is an excerpt of a problem:

> Let $A$ be nonempty set, and let $f:A \rightarrow A$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ is bijective. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f^n$ denote the function $A \rightarrow A$ given by
>
> $$f^n = f \circ \cdots \circ f$$
>
> where $f$ iterated $n$ times.
>
> The function $f^n$ is the **$n$-fold iteration** of $f$. We now extend the definition of $f^n$ to all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $f^0 = i_A$ where $i_A: A \rightarrow A$ is the identity mapping. Because $f$ is bijective, it follows that $f^n$ is bijective. Hence $f^n$ has an inverse. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f^{-n} = (f^n)^{-1}$. It can be verified that $f^a \circ f^b = f^{a+b}$ and $(f^a)^b = f^{ab}$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> (1) Let $x,y,z \in A$. Prove that the following holds.
>
> $x = f^n(x)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

The reason why I doubt my solution is because it seems to simple, yet I have no logical reason to fear that my answer is correct. Since the quantifier in the problem is existential, I merely need to exhibit an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the equation holds. Merely setting $n = 0$ will satisfy the equation, and the proof is complete.

Is there a problem with this approach? Is there a way to build an $n$ that is equal to a specific $n_0$, as opposed to $n$ having a concrete value like 0?

Comment: Your solution to the problem as stated is correct. But I have a feeling that the problem intended that you show $x = f^n(x)& for some $n \neq 0$. Can you do that?

Comment: I see no problem with your approach, It is correct. On the other hand maybe they are asking you to find $n \neq 0$ such that $x = f^n (x)$

Comment: But the problem says $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Nonetheless, if we set $n=2$,then $f^2 = f \circ f$. Since $f$ is bijective, the composition $f \circ f$ is bijective, so it has a unique inverse $(f \circ f)^{-1}$. Composing these two functions renders $i_A$, but I don't know if this approach is correct since we want $x = f^n(x)$.

Comment: @user26977 Why would the problem have $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and specifically define $f^0 = i_A$? I also would like to note that this problem has multiple parts where this specific problem is the first component.

Comment: @JonWarneke Why would the problem imply that $n \neq 0$ since we define $f^0 = i_A$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? This doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: They define $f^0 = i_A$ so that the composition property $f^a \circ f^b = f^{a+b}$ holds for all $a,b \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Right, based on @par's answer, my "intended question" needs more assumptions, e.g., $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(m)=m+1$. It follows that
$f^{n}(m)=m+n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The equation $m=f^{n}(m)=m+n$
implies $n=0$. What does this imply?

**Addendum**: If $A$ is finite, the situation is different. Try playing around with $A=\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ (integers modulo some $k$) and $f(m)=m+1$.

Comment: If $n=0$ and $f^n(m) = m+n$, then $f^n(m) = m$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is great in showing a case where the property holds universally in terms of $n$, but this only observes a single case for a particular function. I think the problem wants $f$ to be general and $n$ particular, hence the statement in the problem which says "for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$".

Comment: My point was that if $A$ is infinite, there are cases in which $n$ can only be zero.

Comment: Gotcha, so the property holds for all functions regardless of the domain only for *some* n, namely $n=0$?

Comment: You proved that for all functions it holds for $n=0$, and I gave you an example $f$ in which it ONLY holds if $n=0$. That is, in my example, no other $n$ will work.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I appreciate the specific function. It makes me understand better the rest of parts in the problem.

Comment: It tells you that you answered the problem correctly. Unless other assumptions are made (e.g. $A$ is finite) you cannot say much more.